# How to pass int values to ASP.NET page methods from jQuery?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, pagemethods

I am using ASP.NET page methods with jQuery. Here is my code,

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "Default.aspx/GetRecords",
      data: "{}",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
```

and the ASP.NET page method is,

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetRecords(int currentPage,int pagesize)
{
    // my logic here
}
```

How to pass values for `currentPage` and `pagesize` from jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got it working. My data section must be

```
data: "{'currentPage':1,'pagesize':5}",
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/GetRecords",
    data: {"currentPage": 1, "pageSize": 100},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
```

?

Comment: @codeka when inspected through firebug it `500 internal server error`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{ currentPage: '" +parseInt( $('#currentpage').val()) + "',pageSize:'"+parseInt( $('#pagesize').val()) +"'}",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetRecords",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
                     $("#result").html(data.d);
                 }
        });
```